# Design an OR gate only using Demultiplexers

Tags: digital-design

Show the OR gate operation by only using de-multiplexers.
I know it is quite impractical implementation but these types of questions are being asked in placement tests.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQAZD.png

check out OR gate truth table if you want from the above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is or gate implementation using demux

take 1*2 demux : input as 1
                 selection input as A
then at 0th output of the demux: Not(A.1) = ABar

similar way BBar will get from B.

now take another 1*4 demux: input as 1
                            selection inputs :- ABar & BBar

then at 0th output of the demux: Not(ABar.BBar.1) = A+B

Comment: check dis solution once @Balu_madaraju

Answer (score 0):

If you feed A&B as the inputs to a 1-4 demux, then the output that is 1 when A=0 & B=0 will be the negation of your desired OR; feed that into a 1-2 demux, and then the output that is the opposite of your input will be your OR.  (Sorry I can't be more precise; not sure what naming convention you are using for your demises.)

Comment: Sorry @Scott Hunter , I didn't get your answer. which demux are you using? 1X2 or 1X4. Which of the two outputs are you considering?